# If $a+(1/(a-2))=4 $ then $(a-2)^2+(1/(a-2))^2$ is .

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

If $a+(1/(a-2))=4 $ then $(a-2)^2+(1/(a-2))^2$ is .

Note:
$a^2+(1/(a-2))^2=4^2$

Comment: $(a(a-2)+1)/(a-2)=4$

Comment: $(a^2-2a)/(a-2)+1/(a-2)=4$

Comment: $(a-2)^2+4/(a-2)+1/(a-2)=4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Remark that $$(a-2)^2+\frac{1}{(a-2)^2}=\Big((a-2)+\frac{1}{(a-2)}\Big)^2-2$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thank you so much @claude Leibovici

Comment: hey i wrote that step rainier van es

Comment: @RainiervanEs. I suppose this is a joke (and I hope so) ! Thanks and cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = a-2 $
$$u+2 + \dfrac{1}{u} = 4 \implies  u + \dfrac{1}{u} = 2 $$

square both sides

Comment: nice explanation!.thank you

Comment: you're welcome !